# JS/jQuery - first click ignores first animation, every other click works properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I built this slider, but when I run it on a page, the first click doesn't trigger the first animation.
It triggers the second animation and every other click after that triggers both animations properly.
What am I missing with the first click?

```
// SLIDER

$(".dot").click(function(){

  let currentId = ($(".dot-active").attr("id")[$(".dot-active").attr("id").length - 1]);
  let nextId = event.target.id[(event.target.id).length - 1];

  $(".dot-active").removeClass("dot-active");
  $("#" + event.target.id).addClass("dot-active");

  if(Number(currentId) != Number(nextId)){
    if(Number(currentId) < Number(nextId)){
      $("#slide" + currentId).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 350);
    } else {
      $("#slide" + currentId).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 350);
    };
    $("#slide" + currentId).removeClass("slide-active");
    $("#slide" + currentId).addClass("slide-inactive");


    if(Number(currentId) < Number(nextId)){
      $("#slide" + nextId).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 350);
    } else {
      $("#slide" + nextId).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 350);
    };
    $("#slide" + nextId).removeClass("slide-inactive");
    $("#slide" + nextId).addClass("slide-active");
  };
});
```

made a test version in codepen here: https://codepen.io/Jankko/pen/ZEEEJxL

Comment: Did you put your JS code into `document.load()` or `$(function(){})`?

Comment: Did you check your question again? it works fine on codepen I think.

Comment: Well, that wasn't the issue, however I did put it to the $(document).ready now, thanks a lot for suggestion.

Maybe I explained badly, if you check the codepen you can see that on first click right after the page loads, the first slide just disappears instead of sliding away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `style="display:block"` to the initiation of your active slide, to prevent the instant hiding of the element, just like this:

```
<div id="slide2" class="slide slide-active" style="display: block;">
        ...
</div>
```

Comment: That is awesome, thanks a lot mate. Would you mind trying to explain what is the logic behind that? and how come it works only with inline styling and not for example when I put the display: block to the slide-active class?

Comment: This is because your code adds the class `.slide-inactive` to the previously-active item before finishing the animation, and while `.slide-inactive` applies `display: none`, your element disappears suddenly, but when you write `display: block` explicitly, which is a stronger style than the class, it will stay to exist until the code replaces it with `display: none` after finishing the animation.

Comment: oh I see, so simple setTimeout() also solves this issue. thanks for explanation, very appreciated.